# Is it possible to save a List Item in SP2007 with out closing?

Tags: 2007, list

I have a SP list that has multiple content types but as of now when someone wants to create a new list item they have to click submit to save. When that is done the window closes and if they want to go back and modify or add any data from other content types they have to click submit each time they want to make changes.

Is there a way in SP 2007 to save the item with out closing the window?

Answer (score 1):

not without a custom built interface that leverages the JavaScript functionality of SharePoint. (Addon JS you may require are JQuery (Latest) Backbone and SPServices (A codeplex project)

If this is within what you are capeable of then it isn't that hard a job, but doing something like this I would definitely use JQuery + Backbone libraries to handle the data client side.

It can be complex process if you aren't familiar with this style of coding.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that. Is there any difference in SP 2010 or would the same need to be done?